# How to CD with a space in directory name (command.com)

Tags: windows-xp, ms-dos

I am running Windows XP SP3.  I am using COMMAND.COM (not CMD).  Using CMD is NOT an option in this case.  I am trying to figure out how to change to a directory when there is a space in the directory name.  The cd /? was useless.... Here is what I have done so far:

START > RUN...> COMMAND.COM

```
Microsoft(R) Windows DOS
(C)Copyright Microsoft Corp 1990-2001.

C:\>cd Documents and Settings
Too many parameters - and

C:\>cd "Documents and Settings"
Parameter format not correct -  "Documents

C:\>cd Documents\ and\ Settings
Too many parameters - and\

C:\>cd "Documents\ and\ Settings"
Parameter format not correct -  "Documents\

C:\>cd\Documents and Settings
Too many parameters - and

C:\>cd"\Documents\ and\ Settings"
Parameter format not correct - "\Documents\
```

I am not sure what else to try.  Tab-completion does not work either.  I'm sure this is a simple syntax error that I cannot find.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using command.com, you'll have to use the [8.3 filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename#How_to_convert_a_long_filename_to_a_short_filename) version of the file/directory name. In this case, it's probably DOCUME~1.

```
C:\>cd docume~1

C:\DOCUME~1>
```

I'm curious why you have to use command.com.

Comment: Thank you for the link!  The dir /x came in very handy.  I needed to hyperlink the file with a space in the directory name into a closed (non-externally networked) wiki.  The wiki does not support spaces in the path name, so I knew going with classic 8.3 would forcefully give me the path name without spaces.

Comment: (And I could not upload the file to the wiki)

Answer (score 0):

`cd Docume~1`
Works as command.com support naming with a  max of 8 characters